# Using jQuery to change icon on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, icons

I am trying to use jQuery to make my icons change on `mouseover`. With Semantic UI, some/most icons can be different if you add `"outline"` as a class. For example: `<i class="icon user"></i>` and `<i class="icon user outline"></i>`.

My idea is to simply toggle the class outline with jQuery on `mouseover`, but then I run into a few problems:

1. Because the `a` within `nav` is selected, if you hover over the `li` inside `a`, the function will run again. It should only work if you hover over the whole `a`.
2. It changes all my icons in the navigation dropdown, and not just the one I am hovering on.
3. The effect stays there even when I move my cursor away, and only goes away once I hover over the element again. (perhaps add a `mouseout`?)
4. The `"home"` icon does not have an outline version, so it should not be affected.

I hope the idea is clear.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/erL8x2rd/20/)

HTML

```
<nav class="smallNav">
  <ul>
    <a href="#">
      <li><i class="icon home"></i>Home</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li><i class="icon star outline"></i>Featured</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li><i class="icon newspaper outline"></i>News</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li><i class="icon user outline"></i>Career</li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li><i class="icon envelope outline"></i>Contact</li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

jQuery

```
$('nav a').mouseover(function() {
  $('nav i').toggleClass('outline');
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('nav a').hover(function() {
    if (!$(this).find("i").hasClass("home")) {
    $(this).find("i").toggleClass('outline');
  }
})
```

Edit: Changed the method to hover

It toggle the class only for the `<i>` that is child of that specific `<a>`, and only if it doesn't have the `home` class

Comment: By far the cleanest method and took into consideration that the home icon does not have an outline version, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`hover()`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) instead of `mouseover()`:

```js
$('nav li').hover(
 (e) => $('i', e.target).toggleClass('outline')
);
```

The above code runs the same function on both `mouseover` and `mouseout` event. If you want to run different functions on each, provide the one for `mouseout` as the second param. Otherwise, the one from `mouseover` is ran on `mouseout`, too.

Also, I limited it to the hovered item only: `$('i', e.target)` => `i` elements inside `e.target`, which is the hovered element. See it in action:

```js
$('nav li').hover(
  (e) => $('i', e.target).addClass('outline'),
  (e) => $('i', e.target).removeClass('outline')
)
```

```css
.outline {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
i {
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-right: .5rem
}
li, ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 150px;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
li:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="smallNav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">
      <i class="icon home"></i>Home
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
      <i class="icon star"></i>Featured
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
      <i class="icon newspaper"></i>News
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
      <i class="icon user"></i>Career
    </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">
      <i class="icon envelope"></i>Contact
    </a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

---

**Important**: your current markup is invalid. The only legal direct children of `<ul>` elements are `<li>` elements.

**Note**: even though `hover(toggleClass)` is short, you'll find sometimes one or more elements can get bugged out by missing a `mouseover` or `mouseout` event, at which point it will start working inversed. To prevent that, you should stick to the verbose form:

```
$('nav li').hover(
  (e) => $('i', e.target).addClass('outline'),
  (e) => $('i', e.target).removeClass('outline')
)
```

Comment: @Taplar, can you please be more specific? One reason to use *what* form? Limiting jQuery selectors by providing a DOM element as the second parameter wherever possible is considered very good practice and, if done consistently, greatly improves page performance, as jQuery doesn't need to parse the entire DOM for each element.

Comment: Your second method worked with some alterations:
`$('nav a').hover(
  (e) => $('i', e.target).removeClass('outline'),
  (e) => $('i', e.target).addClass('outline')
)`
But this would still select the home icon, which doesn't have an outline version. Your explanation helped me understand it a lot more though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This could give you a bit more control:

```
function a(e){
   $(e.target).addClass("outline");
}
function b(e){
   $(e.target).removeClass("outline");
}

$("nav a").on("mouseenter", a);
$("nav a").on("mouseleave", b);
```

(not tested)

Obviously, you can adjust a/b method to remove/add class as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I'd think you'd be better off doing this with pure CSS instead of javascript.

```
.icon.home{
     height: 50px;
     width: 50px;
     background-image: url(path_to_image);
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.icon.home:hover{
     background-image: url(path_to_hover_image);
}
```

Comment: I played around with this for a bit by trying to find a way to link to the icon url but I couldn't get it to work. How do you suppose I can make that work, because it would be the easiest method, and also very easy to change when, let's say, you want completely different icons on hover, not just add the `outline` class.

Comment: The :hover can have a different background-image which would change the icon.    The above example doesn't use the outline class at all.

Comment: The problem is that the icon is not a "background", but an imported icon from a library. I did find a way by changing its content through css, but it works better with jQuery in my opinion.